# Dart/Flutter Image library decode Bitmap fails

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-bitmap, flutter-image

I am trying to read a bitmap generated on the platform site
here is the code I use to generate a byte array in android:

```
ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bitmap.getByteCount());
bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(byteBuffer);
return byteBuffer.array();
```

When I try to decode it with the image library it fails (dart code):

```
Image img = decodeBmp(bitmapData);
```

> The method 'getBytes' was called on null.

bitmap data is not empty and looks proper for me

If I instead compress image on the android side to png or jpg than decodeImage (or -Png or -Jpg) works
but I dont want to use bitmap.compress
this code would work with compress

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bufferedBmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
byte[] imageData = baos.toByteArray();
return imageData;
```

Comment: Apparently decodeBmp() expects a jpg or png image. Not a pixels array.

Comment: You need to prepend a simple BMP header to your pixel data, otherwise the decoder can't figure out the width, height, pixel depth, etc of the birthday.

Comment: do you have a code sample maybe?